# Ubuntu 15 Screen Freezes

Tags: drivers, ati

Dragging and dropping a file into Archive Manager causes the screen to freeze, mouse still moves, but can't click or use suggested keyboard strokes to change workspaces, kill programs, etc.  Only solution is a cold reboot.  Never seen this until 15.

```
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Trinity [Radeon HD 7560D]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 2ae0
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Answer (score 0):

Install video drivers by running in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates
```

and reboot.